# Playlist wont continue in background mode

Tags: swift, avfoundation, avplayer

I am having trouble playing a playlist in background mode while the device is locked. It plays the current audio when locked but I am having trouble with it going to the next audio file in background mode.

I am using a collectionView and a custom cell where I am allowing the user to tap and play the audio in that cell. I made it autoplay, so when the audio is done, it scrolls to the next cell automatically and plays that one and so on. All of that works, its just when the device is locked and in background mode that the playing of the next audio cell stops and just wont continue. I do have 3 second dispatch delays in between the load of the next audio file.

Any help or insight is greatly appreciated.

**View Controller**

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

class MainVC: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout, CustomCellDelegate {

var streams: [[String:Any]] = []

@IBOutlet weak var cv: UICollectionView!

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    if let cell = cv.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as? CollectionViewCell {
        cell.delegate = self
        cell.nameLbl.text = streams[indexPath.item]["shortname"] as? String
        return cell
    } else {
        return CollectionViewCell()
    }
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    if thereIsCellTapped != true {

        let item = cv.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as! CollectionViewCell
        self.loadingCell()

        let when = DispatchTime.now() + 3 // change 2 to desired number of seconds
                DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: when) {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            UIView.animate(
                withDuration: 0.5,
                delay: 0,
                usingSpringWithDamping: 1,
                initialSpringVelocity: 1,
                options: [],
                animations: {

                    item.superview?.bringSubview(toFront: item)
                    self.view.layoutIfNeeded()

                },
                }), completion: { (finished: Bool) in
            let theStream = self.streams[indexPath.item]["audioUrl"] as? String
            item.audioStreamSelected(audioUrl: audioUrl!)

            })
            )
           }
        }
    }
}


func closeView(_ cell: CollectionViewCell) {

    let visibleItems: NSArray = indexPath as NSArray
    let currentItem: IndexPath = visibleItems.object(at: 0) as! IndexPath
    let nextItem: IndexPath = IndexPath(item: currentItem.item + 1, section: 0)

    if nextItem.row == streams.count{
        self.cv?.scrollToItem(
            at: IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0),
            at: .right,
            animated: true
        )
    } else {

        self.cv.scrollToItem(at: nextItem, at: .left, animated: true)
        let when = DispatchTime.now() + 3 
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: when) {
            self.collectionView(self.cv, didSelectItemAt: nextItem as IndexPath)
        }
    }
 }
}
```

**Custom Cell**

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation
import MediaPlayer


protocol CustomCellDelegate {
   func closeView(_ cell:CollectionViewCell)
}

class CollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    var player = AVPlayer()
    var playerItem:AVPlayerItem?
let mpic = MPRemoteCommandCenter.shared()
var delegate: CustomCellDelegate?
var _timeObserver:Any?

@IBOutlet weak var nameLbl: UILabel!

@IBAction func closeBtn(_ sender: Any) {

    if let delegate = self.delegate {
        delegate.closeView(self)
    }
}


override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()

    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self,selector: #selector(playerItemDidReachEnd(_:)),name:NSNotification.Name.AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTime,
                                           object: player.currentItem)

    UIApplication.shared.beginReceivingRemoteControlEvents()

    do {
        try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback)
        print("AVAudioSession Category Playback OK")
        do {
            try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true)
            print("AVAudioSession is Active")
        } catch let error as NSError {

            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
    } catch let error as NSError {

        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }

}



func setupNowPlayingInfoCenter() {
    UIApplication.shared.beginReceivingRemoteControlEvents()
    mpic.skipBackwardCommand.isEnabled = false
    mpic.seekBackwardCommand.isEnabled = false

    mpic.playCommand.addTarget {event in
        self.player.play()
        self.setupNowPlayingInfoCenter()
        return .success
    }
    mpic.pauseCommand.addTarget {event in
        self.player.pause()
        return .success
    }
    mpic.nextTrackCommand.addTarget {event in
        return .success
    }
    mpic.previousTrackCommand.addTarget {event in
        return .success
    }

}



func playerItemDidReachEnd(_ notification: Notification) {
    if let _: AVPlayerItem = notification.object as? AVPlayerItem {
        player.replaceCurrentItem(with: nil)
        if let delegate = self.delegate {
            delegate.closeView(self)
        }
        player.pause()
        player.seek(to: kCMTimeZero)

        if (_timeObserver != nil) {
            player.removeTimeObserver(_timeObserver!)
            _timeObserver = nil
        }

    }
}


 func audioStreamSelected(audioUrl: String){
   if let streamer = URL(string: audioUrl){

    let playerItem:AVPlayerItem = AVPlayerItem(url: streamer)
        self.player = AVPlayer(playerItem: playerItem)
        player.replaceCurrentItem(with: playerItem)
        player.actionAtItemEnd = .pause




 if (_timeObserver == nil) {
        _timeObserver = player.addPeriodicTimeObserver(forInterval: interval, queue: DispatchQueue.main) {
            [weak self] time in

             if self?.player.currentItem?.status == AVPlayerItemStatus.readyToPlay {

                }
           }
        }
     }

  }

}
```

Comment: Did you enable the option **"Audio, Airplay, and Picture in Picture"** in Capabilities section of Background Modes?

Comment: Yea, I have that enabled.